# Python import troubles

Tags: python, import

This should be simple, but I am struggling. I want one folder for my code and another folder for my tests, to test the code in the working_code folder.

```
code/
│
├── working_code/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_code.py
│
├── tests/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_some_code.py
│
└── __init__.py
```

However when I try to import the "some_code" module in the "test_some_code" module:

```
import working_code.some_code
```

It gives an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'working_code'
But to my knowledge working_code is a package. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try "from working_code.some_code import func_name"

Comment: Check what `sys.path` contains.  Essentially, to perform a ‘parallel’ import, the `code` directory must be in `sys.path`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python import src modules when running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761041/python-import-src-modules-when-running-tests)

Comment: Yes adding the path did the trick, thanks.