# Python3 ModuleNotFoundError importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, directory, importerror

I have the following directory structure

```
/home/project/src/numeric.py
/home/project/test/test.py
```

I am in trying to run test.py by importing numeric.py:

```
import src.numeric as n
```

Python is giving me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Currently I am in the directory

```
$ cd /home/project/test/
$ python3 test.py
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: src.numeric is the name of a file. I think you need to write in the format `from src.numeric import <function, class etc. or * if you want everything>`

Answer (score 0):

Python is importing the module based on the relative path from the directory the script is executed.

Therefore your input statement evaluates to:

```
/home/project/test/src/numeric.py
```

-> but the file is at:

```
/home/project/src/numeric.py
```

If you want to keep this structure you would have to include the 'src' dir in your path like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../src')
```

[Python import src modules when running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761041/python-import-src-modules-when-running-tests)