# Python import works either in unit testing, or in package environment, but not both

Tags: python, import

This problem has been eating away at me for a while. For some reason, the way I import my modules works only either for testing or for library usage. Both times the error is a Module not found error. Say I have the following Python repo:

```
- src
  - example
    - dir
      - internal.py
      - __init__.py
    - main.py
    - __init__.py
- test
  - test_main.py
  - __init__.py
- setup.cfg
- setup.py
```

Within `setup.cfg`, I have:

```
[metadata]
name = wf
version = 1.0.0

[options]
include_package_data = True
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

I don't want the user to import from `src`, but instead import from `example`. After all, nobody imports from `src`, and this is the conventional structure, right?

However, now I've been encountering 2 types of errors, depending on my choice:

### Choice 1

For python files in `src` and `test`, all imports are of the form `from src.example.... import ...`. In this case, unit tests work without issues, in particular `python -m unittest discover test`. However, if I create a virtual environment in a separate directory, and pip install this directory and run

```
# script.py
from example.main import ...
# code that calls functions in main that import from internal.py
```

I encounter `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'dir'`. Only if I remove the `src` from imports do I avoid this issue.

### Choice 2

I'm guessing the error is because of how I defined the setup in my `cfg` file, so I remove `src` from `src.example.... import ...` within the example directory. But now, my unit tests fail! This time, the error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir'`.

---

I've looked into some other options.

- Relative imports: I've heard relative imports are fragile, so I avoid them in favor of absolute imports, which IDEs like PyCharm support very easily.
- Sys add path: I've heard that people have complained about how this is a wordy solution, and it is not agnostic, and I agree since I plan to scale up testing, so I would like to avoid it too if possible. I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761041/python-import-src-modules-when-running-tests) post. I'm also aware of the 'nose' suggestion underneath, but do we really need a 3rd party for this?

This has to be a commonly encountered issue... if someone knows where the fix lies, or if there is some template example Python repository which addresses these concerns, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: You will need to install the package before it may be imported normally across any working directory as `from example import ...`. Moreover, your `setup.py` does not contain the required code to actually setup the package.  Please refer to [What is setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py) for a guide.

Comment: @metatoaster by working directory do you mean the test directory?

Comment: As in, no matter where what working directory the program is started from, e.g. can start from `/home/user`, `/`, `/tmp`, anywhere, with the import statement working as expected.

Comment: I see, I made some changes and it worked. I was under the misconception that the test directory didn't require a package install, and that the test directory had different properties than an ordinary working directory in that it was supposed to call the code from the project directly instead of from the package. Thanks.

Comment: There are situations where the scenario you have described (i.e. testing) will work, but this typically require manipulation of `PYTHONPATH` and thus non-standard.  Just make sure your package is created/installed correctly in the active Python environment for a sane working state.